# VLC swaps blue and red

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have a video that VLC plays wrong. The blue and red are switched. It looks weird but not bad. Is there a way for me to correct this? WindowsMediaPlayer gets the colors right. The video type is CRAM (ugh)

Answer (score 1):

Is it the problem with VLC/hardware, or some custom configuration?

To check this:

- Backup current VLC installation files,
- Reinstall it, and when installing, check to remove all settings,
- See if the colors are inverted again. If so, it does not come from your configuration.

### If it is a VLC/hardware issue:

Update VLC to the latest version (1.1.2).

If you already have the latest version of if the update did not solved the problem, you can report the problem to [VLC bugtracking application](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/), indicating the problem and the OS and the hardware you have (sound card and/or motherboard).

### If it is an issue with the settings:

See:

- *Tools* → *Effects and Filters* → *Video Effects*.
- *Tools* → *Preferences* → *All* (radio button, left bottom, "Show settings") → *Video*.